# Прием тела (chunked) http сообщения с ошибкой в формате

Tags: http

Хотел задать один вопрос, а получилось несколько (надеюсь взаимосвязанных).

Как Вы считаете, что надо делать, если принимаемое в HTTP 1.1 (rfc2616) сообщение с телом, объявленным

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

вместо нормального конца очередной части и заголовка новой содержит "галиматью" ?

Я вижу следующие варианты:

1. Остановиться на этом месте и отдать прочитанное обработчику
2. Читать дальше, пытаясь "восстановиться в смысле chunks"
3. Читать до конца потока (EOF или таймаут)

Какие будут предложения ?

Также интересно (пока не смог найти) chunked и Connection: keep-alive совместимы между собой или нет ? ***upd {*** *Уже не интересно. Совместимы.* ***}***

И если совместимы, то что делать с соединением в случае подобной ошибки ?

**Upd 1**

[[@razielsd](/users/6821/razielsd)](/users/6821/razielsd),
Что значит игнорируй запрос ? Понятно, что исполнять его не надо,
а отвечать что ?

И что делать если это не запрос мне? а ответ на мой запрос ?

Вообще, закрывать Keep-Alive соединение ? И если нет, то что делать с 
посылаемыми данными ? читать их до таймаута (каким его делать) или как определить конец передачи ?

*Что-то я в этом RFC не найду алгоритмов обработки подобных ошибок.*

**Upd 2**

Сформулирую вопросы еще раз.

1. При такой ошибке Keep-Alive соединение закрывать ?
2. Если эта ошибка возникла при запросе (POST), то выдать ответ *HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request format* ?

Comment: "Благими намерениями выложена дорога в Ад"

не нужно ничего пытаться восстановить, будет только хуже. Если данные не соответствуют ожидаемым нужно выдать соответствующую ошибку.

Comment: Если знаком с php, посмотри как это сделано в Zend_Http (Zend Framework).

Comment: @shurik, Вы предлагаете для responce (на мой request) просто закрыть соединение, а в подобном случае для request ("браузер" выдал POST мне), как Вы думаете - отсылать ответ с ошибкой и закрывать или сразу закрыть ? 

IMHO передать ему ошибку  лучше.

Я правильно понял Вашу идею ?

--

@razielsd, с php и Zend не знаком. 

В двух словах - как там поступают ? 

Насколько понимаю там подобная ситуация возможна только для request (запрос (POST) от браузера).

Comment: Все, немного ступил, понял суть проблемы :)
Если ты не знаешь как обработать входящие данные - игнорируй этот запрос.

Как определяешь, что там галиматья ? это бинарный протокол, там может быть что угодно, это просто кодированый набор блоков различного размера.

Comment: >Насколько понимаю там подобная ситуация возможна только для request (запрос (POST) от браузера).

Нет, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" обычно используется для ответов.

Comment: @razielsd, по поводу бинарный протокол:

chunk заканчивается CRNL потом идет заголовок следующего - Number[Params]CRNL у последнего 0CRNL.

Вот так определяю. Галиматья это если формат заголовка чанка плохой.

Второй комментарий (Нет, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" обычно используется для ответов.) не понял. 

IMHO php это сервер. Он может обнаружить подобную ошибку в запросе к нему (т.е. в POST). Если Вы утверждаете, что в запросе chunked не применяется, то что смотреть в Zend ?

--

Теперь главное - (черт, не поместится. см **Upd 1** в вопросе).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) речь идет о библиотеке, для обращения к внешним ресурсам.

В случае "галиматьи", если запрос к вам - игнорируйте запрос и отдавайте статус "400 Bad Request", если это вы получаете ответ - логируйте и игноруйте, далее уже разбирайтесь в чем именно проблема.

Comment: Остается вопрос, что делать если это Keep-Alive соединение. Закрывать ? IMHO да.

Comment: Я бы закрыл, не думаю, если стал получать "галиматью", получится "восстановить" соединение.